# "insert ignore" or "on duplicate key update" using @Query & @Modifying without using nativeQuery or save() or saveAndFlush() JPA Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, insert-update

My example is below:

Person is a simple Entity with 3 fields "Long id, String name, Integer age", and, maps to a corresponding Person table with 3 columns per above)

```
@Repository
public interface PersonRepository extends JpaRepository<Person,Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Query(? - what goes here - ?)
    public int modifyingQueryInsertPerson(@Param("id")Long id, @Param("name")String name, @Param("age")Integer age);
}
```

Is there way to do the insert by just using @Query & @Modifying (i.e. without using native SQL query & nativeQuery=true, or, save(), or, saveAndFlush() ?

IMPORTANT>>
Additionally I want to be able to update the records when the record already exist in the table like  "insert ignore" or "on duplicate key update"?

Please help.

Comment: That will only work with native sql simply because that construct doesn't exists in JPQL (yet?). So you will need a native SQL statement.

Comment: But using Native query is going to take away the flexibility to migrate to a different database then what is the point of using JPA if I have to use Native query.

Comment: Because what you want to achieve is simply not possible with JPA / JPQL. As there is no common denominator for doing UPSERT/MERGE statements yet. Hence JPA doesn't support it and you have to write it. Changing a database is kind of a fallacy and unless you write a product that needs to run on multiple databases that would entail a lot more than just rewrite some queries.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution but it's not working for "insert ignore" or "on duplicate key update":

```
@Repository
public interface DualRepository extends JpaRepository<Dual,Long> {
    @Modifying
    @Query("insert into Person (id,name,age) select :id,:name,:age from Dual")
    public int modifyingQueryInsertPerson(@Param("id")Long id, @Param("name")String name, @Param("age")Integer age);
}
```